# How to switch Apache MPM from Prefork to Event?

Tags: apache, debian, apache2.4, apache-modules

How to switch MPM Prefork to Event on Apache 2.4, Debian 8? I have already installed php-7 and php-fpm but can not find a complete tutorial on switching MPM Prefork to Event. I tried [this](https://scottlinux.com/2014/06/18/switch-to-or-enable-apache-event-mpm-in-ubuntu-14-04-for-http-connections/) but MPM Prefork is still running instead of Event.

Answer (score 4):

I did the following steps one by one:

```
su
export PATH=$PATH:/sbin
a2dismod php7.1
a2dismod mpm_prefork
a2enmod mpm_event
a2enmod proxy_fcgi
a2enconf php7.1-fpm
systemctl restart apache2
```

If `php7.1-fpm` is not installed, you can install it before the mentioned steps using `apt-get install php7.1-fpm` or you  can check if it is installed using `dpkg -l {package_name}`

finally, you can make sure of what you did using:
`apachectl -V`

Comment: I guess that works, but why not just use `sudo` (safer & no path should be needed):      `sudo a2dismod phpX.X mpm_prefork` && `sudo a2enmod mpm_event proxy proxy_fcgi` && `sudo a2enconf phpX.X-fpm` && `sudo systemctl restart apache2` <- sub your php version. See  https://wiki.debian.org/sudo

Comment: @B.Shea Yes. It is also true. I wrote that just for summarization.

Comment: NP. BTW you have `proxy_fcgi`, but you need to add the `proxy` module since it's a dependency: See last comment by me -> `sudo a2enmod mpm_event proxy proxy_fcgi` - see deps for https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html - "This module requires the service of mod_proxy."

Comment: So @B.Shea if you suggest to introduce `a2enmod proxy` I would agree

Answer (score -1):

Do,  `a2query -M` to check current mpm_ worker(either prefork, event or worker).
Suppose its currently `prefork`.

So, if you want to switch to `mpm_event` .
Go to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`  and do `ls -la` there will be symbolic links of `mpm_prefork.conf and mpm_prefork.load` .

THEN rename the `mpm_prefork` links to anything else (could be `mpm_prefork2.conf and mpm_prefork2.load`).

To Rename (run these commands) : `cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled` and

`mv mpm_prefork.conf mpm_prefork2.conf`  &

`mv mpm_prefork.load mpm_prefork2.load`

And then create new symbolic links `mpm_event.conf and mpm_event.load` from /mods-available to /mods-enabled like this :

1. `sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_event.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_event.load`
2. `sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_event.conf /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_event.conf`
3. And restart apache. `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Now, do `a2query -M` it will display `event` now.
You have successfully switched `mpm_prefork to mpm_event`

Comment: For Debian, it is better if you don not touch those `.conf` files directly and use the `a2enmod` and `a2dismod` commands.

As a bonus, you can be notified about potential misconfigurations: for example that the module `php7.x` is not compatible with `mpm_event`.  Therefore you would disable it first with `a2dismod` and then:

1. `sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork`
2. `sudo a2enmod mpm_event`